# Which hogan.js templeting package to use with express.js?

Tags: node.js, express, npm, hogan.js

The `hogan.js` template package that `express` provide is `hjs`, however, that package last update was a year ago, and the repo at github got issues opened also a year ago (though not really crucial ones).

There also seems to be more than one `hogan.js` package for `express` tempting at `npm` which left me confused!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you see hjs source code, it's only 63 or so lines and it require hogan.js to work, so it's just a wrapper to make it work on express.
The one I used is [hogan-express](https://github.com/vol4ok/hogan-express) which is also a wrapper for hogan.js (it's required in package.json) and it's no more than 150.

My point, to try to clarify things, it's that the important module is hogan.js all the rest modules to integrate in express are just wrappers. I believe is also worth to give a try to the [consolidate](https://npmjs.org/package/consolidate) module which also support Hogan.

By looking to githubs stars (not necesarily quality indicator) you will see

consolidate (*548) > express-hogan(*48) > hjs (*8)

If you are wondering why hjs was the "chosen" for the express command line the answer is [this pull request](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/pull/1176/files) You can see by your self what it takes to implement another module. So may be some one should report if hjs is giving problems and there is a better alternative. It's not hard  to change it in express.